# I got error on josn.decode(resp) ( Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>' when )

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code which I was trying to execute.............
Help Me to solve this problem..

I tried many ways searching the solution of this to everywhere but I cant solve it.

The error being thrown is

> Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List'

My flutter details is:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2  
  
  dio: ^3.0.10

class SearchList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SearchListState createState() => _SearchListState();
    }
    
    class _SearchListState extends State<SearchList> {
      String _url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1";
      TextEditingController _textcontroler = TextEditingController();
      StreamController _streamController;
      Stream _stream;          
      JsonCodec codec = new JsonCodec();
    
      _serch() async {
    if (_textcontroler.text == null || _textcontroler.text.length == 0) {
      return _streamController.add(null);
    } else {
      try {
        Map<String, String> requestheader = {"Accept": "application/json"};
        final response = await Dio().get(_url, queryParameters: requestheader);
        final jsondata = response.data;

        var decoded = json.decode(jsondata);
        //here I got error 
        /// Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
        /// I AM stuck here I was tried by making a class but the error was the same...

        print(decoded);
        return _streamController.add(decoded);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error: $e");
      }
    }
  }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _streamController = StreamController();
        _stream = _streamController.stream;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Item Name"),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _textcontroler,
                      onChanged: (String text) {
                        _serch();
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter Item Name",
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
                          border: InputBorder.none),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Text("Enter Some data");
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data["name"].length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var alldata = snapshot.data[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: alldata["name"],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: you don not need to decode the ```jsondata```. just directly use it.

Comment: what is the response json you are fetching from api?

Comment: here is the API which is I used for response https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1

Comment: I write a code, would you try it?\

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is you call `json.decode` which expects a json string but you already have a decoded `List<dynamic>`. `Dio` internally decodes your response and returns you the decoded output.

You can directly use the `response.data` or type cast it for better IntelliSense like this:

```dart
final jsonData = response.data as List<Map<String,dynamic>>; //<-- converts List<dynamic> to List<Map<String,dynamic>>

return _streamController.add(jsonData); //<-- Use jsonData directly
```

If you want to access the post details from the API response you can access each Map like this:

```dart
jsonData.forEach((postMap){
  print("postId: ${postMap["postId"]}");
  print("id: ${postMap["id"]}");
  print("name: ${postMap["name"]}");
  print("email: ${postMap["email"]}");
  print("body: ${postMap["body"]}");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should add a model class first

```
class Post {
  int postId;
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String body;

  Post({this.postId, this.id, this.name, this.email, this.body});

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    postId = json['postId'];
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['postId'] = this.postId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

then decode response with `fromJson()` factory of the model like this

```
List<Post> posts = response.data.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
```

then you can use it and access attributes whenever you want

this is the way to decode a custom json

Comment: Does not explain why he got the error. And making a model is not necessary